# different group size same excess rate - which group performed better

Tags: sample-size, ranking, weights

I want to compare the performance of three groups with quite a different group size.
In order to get a 'fair' ranking I thought I might not compare totals or averages but excess rates.

Let's say I have the following:

[image]

So group C is more than twice as big as group A.
Within a group there are some members that fulfill a certain criteria I'm interested in.
For example 19% of all members of group B match this criteria.

Then I'm making a contest and out of the people who were successful I check the rate of this criteria again.
So in group A I would expect again 12% but instead the rate matching my criteria is 13%. So 1 percentage point excess.
Group B has the highest rate with 17% but coming from 19% they only get the third spot in the ranking.

But which one gets to be the winner? Group A and C have both +1pp. Is is group A because from 12 to 13% it an 8.3% growth and from 13 to 14% only 7.7%? I'm still not sure because of the different group sizes. And what would be, if A and C both start with 12% and have 1pp excess?

I've found an approach for frequencies but as the author already states it's not as transparent as one might would want: [How to compare groups with different sizes?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/129332/how-to-compare-groups-with-different-sizes)

Thanks for your help!

**I hope this answers the question from the comments:**

*No, I’m not trying to find out which matching-members perform the best. For example one criteria is age-range. Members will come and go over time. So the matching-members from the beginning are not necessarily matching in the end. The first rate is just to get a baseline. Every matching-member is counted as success.*

*If the contest leads to the case, that a higher proportion of people in the desired age-range sign up, the matching-member rate should increase. If the contest has no effect, I’d expect the rate to stay the same.*

*If all groups would have the same size, the final winner would be the group with the most matching-members. But since the size is so different, I thought excess-rate might solve the problem.*

Comment: Your goal is not very clear.  Are you trying to work out which group members who meet your specific criteria perform best in the contest?  If you can write down exactly what you mean by success or 'winner' at the individual level or group level it will be easier to help.

Comment: @GeorgeSavva is the edit answering your question?